# How do add +/- sign of rows in one column to rows in new column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, multiple-columns

I would like to create a new column in a `data.frame` with the values of one column but using the sign (+ or -; <0 or >0) added. Here is an example.

```
 set.seed(12345)
 df = data.frame(a=c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5), rep("c",7), rep("d",10)), 
    b=rnorm(30, 0, 2), 
    c=rnorm(30, 12, 3.5), 
    d=rnorm(30, 8, 3)
    )
```

How can I create a column d_signed, which has each value of column d, but with the sign of column b? Expected result:

```
 df$d_signed <- c(8.448776, 3.972406, -9.659909, -12.769889, 6.239361, -2.502868, 10.664418,
 -12.780465, -9.550564, -4.112985, -8.163847, 5.646052, 4.851942, 14.991536,
 -12.208116, 10.827803, -10.478775, -5.565379, 9.428745, 11.063775, 9.936149,
 11.129431, -7.086893, -15.431333, -10.913662, 13.601298, -10.016127, 7.076140,
 9.609571, -10.474610)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df$d_signed = abs(df$d) * sign(df$b)`?